# reading large csv files in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, chunks

I would like to read in large csv type of files with the read_csv method and specifying the chunksize to something reasonable (say 1,000,000) in order not to get into memory issue on my Mac (total of 8GB installed only).

So far I would do like, and, in order to limit the resulting DataFrame to something reasonable, I would select say 1 out of 100 users (using the modulo 100 approach)

```
import pandas as pd
iter_csv = pd.read_csv('data/datafile.tsv',delimiter='\t',encoding='utf-8', chunksize= 500000)
df = pd.concat([chunk[chunk['UserID'] % 100 == 1] for chunk in iter_csv])
```

so far so good.
What I really would like to do is to be able to browse thru the various "chunks" as DataFrames by simply passing the number of the chunk. 
How could I do this

Support would be greatly appreciated
Peter

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to look at a specific chunk? You could just determine the number of rows to skip and the number of lines to read and pass these as params to `read_csv`

Comment: Sorry from my side, I was not clear!

Comment: Sorry from my side, I was not clear! the use case is to look at the data from the csv file chunk by chunk so to get an idea what is the data looking like. So, a function like    def look_at_chunk(chunk_number): ........... Example: I have a csv file of 10M rows and I specify chunksize being 1M, hence I have 10 chunks on the iter_csv iterator. Now I would like to look at chunk say 4 as a DataFrame (so data from the 4Mth to the 5Mth row) and browse the data before doing more analysis on it.

Comment: I have here a little code that does something in the direction I am looking for, but very much not elegant at all 'iter_csv = pandas.read_csv(open(trainCsvPath, 'rb'), delimiter='\t', chunksize=10 ** 6)

browseDF = pd.DataFrame()
def browseChunk(chunkItem):
    i = 0
    for chunk in iter_csv:
        if i == chunkItem:
            browseDF = chunk
            break
        i = i + 1
    print browseDF,

'

Comment: @PeterHIRT I was thinking about the same approach previously, but find it works pretty well when you access the first few chunks, but very slow if you try to access the last few chunks.